# Mail sending error

Tags: laravel-5.3, mamp

I have an error displaying when trying to test rest password fonctionality for laravel.

This error is displayed:

`Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q130sm23434521wmd.29 - gsmtp
"`

Comment: I'm using MAMP on my MAC i think the problem reside in MAMP configuration but i have no idea how to configure it.

Comment: It's easier for you to use services like `mailgun` instead of local. If you use it for testing, you can use `mailtrap`.